# Are there any ways to open new credit while abroad?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit, travel, working-abroad

background- I do have a mailing address and someone I trust to collect it.
I have been outside of the US since 2009 and am unfamiliar with any changes in the banking rules since "The Financial Crisis".

I would like to find a credit union that has cards for people with little or no credit history.

Comment: You can apply for credit online and they'll mail you a card, so I'm not sure exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks for the comment. I will add more substance to the question.

Comment: Why not apply for a card where you currently live?

Comment: @BobbyScon I already have one but, it will not improve my US credit rating as they do not report to US credit bureaus. I want to improve my US credit report and have a 2nd line while I am traveling to the US. It is easier to pay a bank where I am physically located then trying to pay back an overseas bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption you're not looking for a particular credit union/bank (since that'll make this question off topic), you can apply for a secure credit card. That's where you essentially put up a sum of money as collateral. That would be the safe way for someone with "little or no credit history" and wants to build credit. Any big bank (Wells Fargo, Chase, etc.) should be able to do that for you. You can also do that online provided you have the means to transfer money into the account.